# make an element the same height as its child with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code and the child's height is changing but the parent's height remains the same. I want a CSS code to make the parent's height the same as the child

```
<div class = "parent">
  <div class="child">

</div>

</div
```

Comment: this should be the natural behaviour, so maybe you have set a fixed height for the parent or maybe the child is out of the flow because is positioned. Please provide the minimal style to reproduce the issue

Comment: it's Slick slider,so when the slide changes the wrapper still the same height and the adaptiveheight isn't working @FabrizioCalderan

Comment: .parent { height: fit-content; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

Note: using your HTML

if you add the CSS

```
<style>
    .parent, .child { 
      width: 120px; height: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class = "parent">
  <div class="child">    
  </div>  
</div
```

both child and parent would have the same width and height of: 120, by 100. Change these values to suite what you need.

if you add this additional CSS lines:

```
.parent { border: 1px solid red; }
.child { border: 1px solid blue }
```

this will draw your border - in different colours, so you can see easily what is happening - you can remove this after